# Using the word "So" too much that it is annoying

Tags: figures-of-speech, discourse-markers

So, ...........I'm tired of using the word "so" and I'm tired of hearing everyone using it also!  What are alternatives and how long will it be before I can make myself stop using it?

Comment: So...could you give us an example?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about help to stop using "so" as a filler when speaking.

Comment: I've often edited out the word "So" when it meaninglessly appears as the first word in an ELU question. I know it's not uncommon in *speech*, but it always looks really "ignorant" to me in written contexts where there's no preceding text for it to reference. I think this particular question may be the *only* "valid" way of using it to introduce a discourse (but I still don't like it, even here! :)

Comment: Try these alternatives: Well, [...] / Now, [...] / OK, [...] However, as Gary's Student suggests, it's better to avoid this kind of verbal filler altogether. Words like that are easy to overuse, and as you've noticed, soon get tiresome for all concerned. To wean yourself off the habit, why don't put $1 (or a banknote of whatever currency you use) in a kind of swear-box for pointless speech mannerisms whenever you catch yourself at it. Tell your family you will use the money to buy spinach or brussels sprouts, and you'll all be eating it. You'll find them eager to help you kick the habit. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try dropping the word and only use a substitute only if it is absolutely necessary.

*What do you think?*

rather than

*So, What do you think?*

This is easier to achieve in writing vs speaking.